# How to create a list from a column in another file?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file in table form.

I want to convert the second column from that file into something that looks like this:

value 1, value 2, value 3    (so a list)

How do I do this in R?

Comment: just call `data[, 2]`

Comment: @Onyambu this doesn't create a new list, just a new table with just that column

Comment: `data[,2]` will output a vector. If you want a list then do `as.list(data[,2])`. This will break up the vector and store each element as a list item.

Answer (score 0):

Onyambu is correct but you may be very new to R to understand.
Here are a few things you may want :

ll = list(data[,2]) or ,

ll = as.vector(data[,2]) // use as.numeric() or as.integer() or as.Date() etc for other conversions.